# How to make Ruby file run as executable?

Tags: ruby, windows, scripting, executable

I want my Ruby Script File to run as executable from any directory of Windows XP. I have created a test.rb (Ruby Script file) and want to run it from any directory of my Windows as "test" for example, "C:\test" or "C:\Directory\test" runs my file test.rb.

```
#!/usr/bin/envy ruby

p "Hi this is my test file"
```

I have added the shebang code in my ruby file but when I have to run the Ruby Script, I have to locate my Script file and run it expicitly as "ruby test.rb".

I have also made the file executable by executing the command:`$ chmod +x hello-world.rb`
, but it still does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I launch a ruby script from the command line by just its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name)

Comment: What OS are you on, and how do you want to run the script (command line or GUI)?

Comment: "#!/usr/bin/envy ruby" should be `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Comment: @Phrogz: I have mentioned my OS as Windows XP in the first line.. And yes I want to run it through command line..

Comment: OK. I/we were confused because the shebang line makes no difference in Windows XP, and `chmod +x` [does nothing](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/chmod.1.asp) on Windows XP (when it exists at all). Since you want Windows XP, the duplicate question found by @KenBloom above applies directly and answers your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you're using Linux or OS X and creating the file on a disk accessible from Windows? Windows does not use shebangs, and it does not use Unix file modes. You will need to associate files with the `.rb` extension to the Ruby executable; details for that operation can be found at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name); once you have done this, you can run `C:\whatever\test.rb` or `C:\whatever\test` to execute the script.

Comment: This doesn't help if you want to send your new program to someone else, who doesn't have Ruby installed..