# creating shell commands for ruby script

Tags: ruby, shell, unix

Suppose i have a ruby script that prints some message like `Hello World`

Now, can i make custom shell command like `printMessage` which passes the control to my ruby script ?

so that whenever i type `printMessage` from the command line, it prints `Hello World` ?

Comment: Making the ruby file run as executable should accomplish what you want, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518297/how-to-make-ruby-file-run-as-executable

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but the question would be a better fit on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .bashrc or .bash_profile

```
alias printMessage='ruby /path/to/file.rb'
```

Should do it. Unless I misunderstood the question.

And `puts` will print to command line. And you have to reload your bash profile once you've done this to get it to work. Just type `source ~/.bashrc` to reload it.

May have to `chmod` the file.

Alternative:

```
alias printMessag='ruby -e "puts \"Hello World\""'
```

Should work too.