# Can I avoid writing 'ruby'?

Tags: ruby, windows-7

Every time I run a program in ruby, I need to prepend the "ruby" command e.g. `ruby program_name.rb`

Are there any alternatives to avoid this? Like directly writing `program_name.rb` or just `program_name`?

P.S. I am working on Windows(7)
I have many files and want to run each file separately. Can't make a batch file for each ruby file.

Comment: have you tried associating the .rb extension with the Ruby executable? See http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default

Comment: @Mischa I think it's more likely a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name

Comment: @Iain, yeah, sorry. Can't change it anymore, but that one is more appropriate.

Comment: vikbehal, if an answer from the other pages works for you, please let us know and we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Its not working. I read a book, same method is said. Maybe Issue with Win7. Not Sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a batch file program_name.bat which contains

```
ruby program_name.rb
```

and run it.

Comment: No, I have many files and want to run each file separately. Can't make a batch file for each entry.

Comment: You should edit your question and add this, you will get better answers this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this on Windows using the following guide:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world#Windows

(I still do not recommend Windows for Ruby programming, however)

Comment: Why not on Windows? I have just started learning RUby. Can you also suggest best book/blog for this?

Comment: I don't want to give out downvotes, but in what way is that helpful to the OP? Especially the last line.

Comment: Actually, the page you link to *does* describe how to do it in Windows (at the bottom). If you change your answer and point your link to the correct part of that page, I can undo my downvote.

Comment: I second Mischa's suggestion.