# running script after specified time in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby script open.rb

```
require 'launchy'

 Launchy.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Now what i want is that in a day i run script first time than it should run after every 10 minute. 
so is there any way to do this and here i am using windows 7.

After google on this i got a way to do it Ruby on Rails with worker as a background job but that is not my solution so is there any possible way to do it or is there any gem to do this task.

and also how can i clear chache before running this.

Comment: how about using Windows Scheduler instead?

Comment: There how can i run ruby script and i want to run it after every 10 min and as i know we can run minimum i time in a day

Comment: The question is for windows-7 tag I think.

Comment: @user1944856 , yes you can. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Windows Scheduler.

To set the task run every 10 minutes, follow the solution in this Stack Overflow question: [windows scheduler to run a task every x-minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/windows-scheduler-to-run-a-task-every-x-minutes)

**UPDATE**: here is a way to run associate Ruby script to `ruby.exe` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422398/188331 ( you can make a batch script )

Comment: Than how can i run ruby script in schedular