# How to run a file in Windows cdm that is a one directory deeper?

Tags: cmd, windows-xp

I have a file that I want to run in this directory:

```
C:\ruby\App\bin\cucumber
```

And I have a file that I want to pass it in this directory:

```
C:\ruby\App\features\creating_projects.feature
```

All works fine when I explicitly `cd` to `/bin` and run the file:

```
C:\ruby\App>cd bin
C:\ruby\App\bin>cucumber ..\features\creating_projects.feature
```

But I want to be able to run it being in my app's root directory. But this doesn't work. It says, `"bin\cucumber" is not a program, command of file`:

```
C:\ruby\App>bin\cucumber features\creating_projects.feature
# error
```

How can I run the file this way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
C:\ruby\App>.\bin\cucumber ..\features\creating_projects.feature
```

?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I also tried to do it with `start` command. The same result - `not a program`

Comment: Hmm, it seems like you're calling the directory instead of the file (That's why I thought you could try the ".\" before bin. Anyways: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you should add file extension

> C:\ruby\App>bin\cucumber.??? features\creating_projects.feature

Comment: The thing is that that file (`cucumber`) doesn't have an extension.

Comment: I thought so. I think, there is no association with that type of file. Windows don't know what program use to run it. Which application do you use to start such files?