# Run cmd with parametrs from c# code

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, cmd

Let's say i have button on my form (i use c#)

```
private void yesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

how and what i need to write, so that i can call my ruby cmd file?

for example in cmd i write:

```
cd c:\ruby\ 
ruby 1.rb 
(here i need to pass some var's) 
root 
123
```

how can i call this in my c# .net app? also i need to see cmd output on some form component (which is best) ?

also i need to call this in "multi-task", so call this cmd let's say 10 time in ~ on time...

Comment: How would you call it from the command-line?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud i need to start cmd and pass there values inside form app, and then use cmd in form

Comment: Does your ruby script read from the standard input?

Comment: Try the above http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121408/Step-by-step-guidance-for-calling-a-IronRuby-Metho

Comment: @JohnKällén what do you mean? yes, it's read cmd input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you're question is still real vague, but you can do it like this:

```
var pathToRbFile = @"C:\Ruby193\script\123.rb";
var arguments = string.Empty; // I don't know what the arguments would be

var info = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToRbFile, arguments);
Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: wouldn't the .rb file be the argument and the first parameter the path to the ruby executable in this case? otherwise this should work.

Comment: @krizz, the `.rb` file should already be executable by the shell in general. `Process.Start` leverage the normal shell execution.

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris, I don't know all of that information because I don't know anything about ruby. But as I stated in my answer, the first parameter is the fully qualified path to the `.rb` file and then the second parameter is a `string` of arguments. What that path is, and what those arguments are, that's something you'll have to work out.

Comment: forget about ruby, just imagine that i have rb file in "C:\\Ruby193\\scripts" and there i must execute command ruby 123.rb, how to write code than? also give full code, with creating class instance etc

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris, I've updated my question, but that is all the code. That's all there is to it.

Comment: wait, first i must CD to folder, and then run second command: "ruby 123.rb", how to do then? i must create one more var info = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToRbFile, arguments); ?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris, the code I have will run the ruby file. You're not on the command-line where you need to execute each of those commands. The operating system is going to run the file specified in the path using the shell.

Comment: main problem is that ruby file will not run so, it's must be run only from cmd, with command: ruby 123.rb - so get's on, if i write as you, it will be opened with text editor ^)  so all operation's must be in cmd

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris, that's just because you haven't associated the file extension with the `ruby` executable. Have a look at the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name

Comment: ok, i will accept, also maybe you know how to append this output to form ?

Comment: so i mean this new windows set as tab on form?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris, have a look at this answer on how to redirect the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Comment: i will do this... just 5 min later

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: this file is not executable Win32.  (((

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41551/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-valdis-azamaris)