# Ruby script on windows without keyword

Tags: ruby, windows

I created a little ruby script on **OSX** and i would like to use it on **Windows**.

How can i ask windows to start my script in the ruby environment, without specifying the `ruby` keyword ?

I did it this way on **OSX**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

But on windows i don't know.

I would prefer to not have the `.rb` extension.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I launch a ruby script from the command line by just its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name)

Comment: this is not exactly what i want.

Comment: So what is it that you want then?

Comment: i edited for more precisions.

Comment: On windows, it seems kind of baked in that [type is identified by extension](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq).

Comment: A shell such as git-bash on windows would enable using a #! line if you don't mind using the shell to invoke your script.

Comment: I actually want to use the shell ! I will create a bat file in the dir thank you.